# How to sum up the columns of a pandas dataframe according to the elements in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like this:

```
squareid       nofcolumns  callduration
3959_3_3       3.990301    997.056881
3961_2_2       7.996370   1153.932142
3961_2_3_0     5.345003    760.179554
3961_2_3_1     5.064245   1341.673636
3961_2_3_2    16.816554   2926.182896
3961_2_3_3_0   3.116286    351.698031
3961_2_3_3_1   7.269828   1842.511559
3961_3_2      10.944895   6865.086506
3962_0_1_0     3.116931    674.581507
3962_0_2       8.272328   4330.343234
3962_0_3       3.079968    279.802874
3962_1_0_0     4.015021    344.013988
3962_2_0_1     3.787312   1820.223512
3962_3_1       4.263979    657.806411
3962_3_2_2     4.184289    266.976026
3962_3_3_2     4.797507   1537.279123
3963_1_3_0     7.594542    545.348282
3963_1_3_3     3.845666    186.378080
3963_3_1_2_2   3.350109    505.276355
3963_3_1_2_3   3.229853    302.434752
...
```

I want to aggregate over the two columns of `nofcalls` and `callduration` according to the `squareid` column and write the result file into a new csv file.

What I have tried for this part is:

```
sub_df = sub_df.groupby('squareid').sum()
sub_df.to_csv(filename2,sep = '\t',header = False,index = False)
```

The aggregation worked but in the files that are generated the `squareid` column is missed.

How can I write it like the original file that the `squareid` column be specified?

Comment: What if you say `index=True`?

Comment: Use `df.groupby('squareid', as_index=False).sum()` because `groupby` converts the grouped column to an index by default, which you then omit while saving.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Ah, Thank You very much, yes it worked! My problem is solved.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Just pointing out, I'm not the downvoter, but there's a [war raging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359059/how-well-should-gold-badge-holders-prove-the-correctness-of-their-unhammering?cb=1) so that might explain the collateral damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to say `index=True` to save the index, rather than your current `index=False`.

Comment: isn't `index=True` the default so the OP could remove this

Comment: Yes, it also works well. Thank you.